# ios : Error when compiling xcode project

Tags: ios5

actually i downloaded xcode sample project from some website when i want compile it shows error "My Mac 64-bit".
My iOS project is only showing "My Mac 64-bit" rather than the Simulator or my iPhone to build to. I have no idea why this is happening. I do not think that I have changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your project name in XCode. In the detail view click on Info tab. In the deployment target section, set it to whatever it was earlier.[image]

Or just try restarting XCode.